# Returning multiple times in Django views and proceed code execution

Tags: python, django

How can I return something and still proceed? In this case, `Hello World` should be printed in the console. I want to keep the return because i need to execute a function that returns either `None` or an Httpresponse

```
def filter_pending_documents(request):
    return pass #code should not stop here
    print('Hello World')
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: Your logic has a flaw. Either you call a second function or you write some If else statments. What are you trying to achive? Return is the end of a function there is no way around that. rewrite your function....

Answer (score 2):

Whenever your function reaches a `return` statement, it will exit out of the function.

So, in your case, you want to remove that line from your code for it to work, as

```
def filter_pending_documents(request):
    print('Hello World')
    return HttpResponse('')
```

if you need your function to return either `None` or the `HttpResponse`, you need to provide a condition for each case (an `if` statement). Remember, if the function reaches any `return` statement, it will exit out. One example to achieve what you want is as follows

```
def filter_pending_documents(request):
    print("Hello World!")
    if 2 > 1: # replace with your own condition
        return None
    else:
        return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: Correct, but that conditions belong to a different function outside of the view. If that function returns None, I want to continue the script inside of the view. Is this possible to do it without an if? e.g. `return function_call()` if function_call return none continue.

Comment: almost. In that case what you want is `if function_call() is None:` and then `else:` for the otherwise case...

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `return pass` from there and it will work fine

When a function reaches a return statement it will break even if there is code after

Answer (score 1):

remove the pass statement because it used on an empty class, function, if and for block
for different purposes
and make sure you iport the HttpResponse like `from django.http import HttpResponse`

```
def filter_pending_documents(request):
    string = 'Hello World'
    return HttpResponse(string)
```

or you can not the returning object in the variable like

```
def filter_pending_documents(request):          
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

or create the markup page in the template and render it like this

```
def filter_pending_documents(request):
    return render(request, 'hello world.html')
```